# Super Mario Odyssey Downgrade Digital Version to 1.0.0 or 1.1.0

Tags: nintendo-switch, super-mario-odyssey, speedrun

Since v1.2.0 came out for odyssey, many wall clip glitches used by speed runners were patched out.

This forced them to buy the physical copy and reset factory their switch, turn wifi off, etc. just to get the game back to 1.0.0, since if you try to update the game it will automatically update to the latest version, so already there's no clear solution to get odyssey back in v1.1.0, even with the physical copy.

This is really inconvenient to have to buy the physical copy and reset factory the switch just to play odyssey in v1.0.0, yet I do realize that some still speedrun the game in 1.2.0, but generally 1.1.0 speedruns have proven to be more successful ([according to the current leaderboards](https://www.speedrun.com/smo/full_game)).

Is there really no other way to downgrade to 1.0.0 or 1.1.0 with the digital copy of Super Mario Odyssey or any other digital game realistically? This is very annoying and obscure ... perhaps there's a work around procedure for this?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to downgrade a digital game on the nintendo switch

Comment: How about for downgrading the physical version to v1.1.0 at least?

Comment: Physical version should be possible in theory.  AFAIK the game updates are stored somewhere in your console/SD card; not the game memory.

Comment: Are the cartridges updated? Like after they released 1.2 would all cartridges coming out of the plant where they produce them would have 1.2 on them, instead of being 1.0 and having to upgrade as soon as you plug it in at home? If so, you would have to find a cartridge created when the factory was in 1.1 mode.

Comment: @Fredy31 I don't think they would change the cartridges after every single update.

Comment: @JMac And how exactly do you access those?

Comment: @WEB_UI No idea, hence the "in theory".

Comment: Great job Nintendo, you've done it again.

Comment: Switch gamecards are read only, which is a pity. I would have loved to save space on the Switch by having updates on the gamecard.

Comment: Looking at the leaderboards right now is not an indicator that 1.1.0 is significantly faster than 1.2.0.  The update hasn't been out for long enough for 1.2.0 runs to have an impact on the boards.

Comment: Also, the only useful speedrun trick that got patched out was the frog glitch.  The wall clips were made a lot harder, but that only saved significant time in world peace runs.  You can still get a great time without those tricks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the cartridges don't change version like in the N64 days, you have 2 choices. Starting at 1.0 on a wifi disabled switch with the physical game; or playing on the latest version on digital/wifi enabled switch.

The only way to play 1.1 (or any version between 1.0 and latest) would be to

1. Emulate it
2. By some kind of sorcery flash your own cartridge with a 1.1 rom.

Both options seem like pretty hard to do as of now. So I would say you will have to give up. The records that are recorded in the 1.1 version are now pretty much untouchable and skips/glitches that were available only in the 1.1 version are now unusable.

Answer (score 4):

This should help you (https://www.speedrun.com/smo/guide/qbeq4,
Credits goes to Smallant1):

> HOW TO GET 1.0.0:
>
> There are two methods currently that do not require "hacking" your
>   switch to obtain 1.0 and keep your save files for other games
>
> METHOD 1 Requirements
>   -Physical Copy of SMO with serial number ending in 000
>   -Willingness to temporarily lose access to your SMO save data
>   -Nintendo Switch Online
>
> 1. Backup the save data for all of your games on your switch using the Switch Online Cloud Feature
> 2. Factory reset your Switch.
> 3. Start up your Switch (DO NOT ENABLE INTERNET YET).
> 4. Turn off auto-updates.
>
> At this point, you can play SMO 1.0.0 and have no problems whatsoever,
>   but you don't have your save files back, so...
>
> 5. Turn on internet.
> 6. Redownload any games, and save data from the cloud. DO NOT download your SMO save data. If you download it then the game will not start
>      without forcing an update first.
>
> You can now play Mario 1.0.0, but every time you try to boot it up it
>   will show a dialog box that will try to get you to update. You do NOT
>   have to do the update, but the box will still show up. Unfortunately,
>   any games that do not support the Cloud Save Backup will have their
>   save data lost. Keep this in mind. (Splatoon 2, Pokémon Let’s Go, NBA
>   2K19, FIFA 19, Dead Cells, Dark Souls Remastered)
>
> METHOD 2 Requirements:
>   -Physical Copy of SMO with serial number ending in 000
>   -Willingness to lose your SMO save data
>   -A second Switch (Only necessary if you wish to keep save data for other games)
>
> 1. Delete Mario save data from the profile(s) you want to "save" for later.
> 2. Transfer the profile(s) onto another Switch (not necessary if you don't care about other games save data).
> 3. Factory reset your Switch.
> 4. Start up your Switch (DO NOT ENABLE INTERNET YET).
> 5. Turn off auto-updates.
>
> At this point, you can play SMO 1.0.0 and have no problems whatsoever,
>   but you don't have that profile yet, so...
>
> 6. Turn on internet.
> 7. Transfer your user profile back to your Switch from your friend's Switch.
>
> You can now play Mario 1.0.0, but every time you try to boot it up it
>   will show a dialog box that will try to get you to update. You do NOT
>   have to do the update, but the box will still show up.

Comment: This is good info, but I don't think it really answers the OP's question. They wanted to know how to downgrade the *digital* version of the game, and both of your methods require a physical copy.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is no known way to get a switch game back to 1.0 *digitally*. However, you can get a Super Mario Odyssey cartridge with the serial number ending in 000 and use the save data cloud feature to back up the data of all of your other games **EXCEPT** Odyssey. Factory reset your console and boot it back up. Your entire system data should be gone.

Do not allow internet access yet, and once the switch is booted up and running, disable auto-updates in the settings. Then load Super Mario Odyssey. From now on, it will be on version 1.0 unless you update it. Keep in mind, every time you boot up the game, it will ask to update. Just decline and start playing.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unpatched switch you can alternatively hack it and then u can manually take the updates out, although im not sure if this would result in a ban or not if it is on sysnand.