# Downpatch / Legacy - Weapons Switch Glitch does not work

Tags: cuphead

So, I've gone back to the Legacy version of Cuphead by Right Clicking on Cuphead in Library-> Properties-> Betas-> legacy -no patches --use at your own risk. I can see [legacy] next to Cuphead in my games library. So I'm guessing I've done things right. Right?

However, the weapons switch glitch won't work for me. I've have Peashooter and Roundabout equipped, and keep LB pressed. But the Weapons won't switch like they do for speedrunners.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the Weapons Switch Glitch Back?

I've even tried downpatching using the Steam Console. The glitch won't work that way either.

Answer (score -1):

This looks a lot like the question here. [Super Mario Odyssey Downgrade Digital Version to 1.0.0 or 1.1.0](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/327368/super-mario-odyssey-downgrade-digital-version-to-1-0-0-or-1-1-0/327429#327429)

Thing is, maybe the Legacy version is not a version where that glitch exists?

Examples :

- The glitch exists in version 1.1 of the game only.
- Legacy only goes back a set number of versions. If the current version of the game is 1.3, and legacy only goes back one version, you might be playing on 1.2, and the glitch is still removed.
- Legacy forces you to version 1.0; and if the glitch was introduced in version 1.1, you wont have access to it.
- Legacy just stops fetching patches. So if current version is 1.3 (you updated to see the glitch not existing anymore) it won't roll you back. It will keep you at 1.3.

So do some research. What version are you playing. What versions have the glitch in it?

And if I can remember right, you can go fetch a particular build in steam. But I'm at work, and can't look it up right now.

EDIT: A question already covers the subject of pulling an old version of a game via steam. [Can you choose which version of a game to play on Steam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266464/can-you-choose-which-version-of-a-game-to-play-on-steam)